java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR - Capacitor App
build.gradle
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
push notification ts
await PushNotifications.addListener('registration', (token) => {
  if (token?.value) {
    this.service.setlocalData('deviceidentity', {
     console.log(token?.value)
    });
  }
});

await PushNotifications.addListener('registrationError', (err) => {
  console.error('Registration error: ', err.error);
  console.log('Error details: ', err);
});

"@capacitor/push-notifications": "^5.0.0",
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR - Capacitor App
google service JSON - firebase and project also same build.gradle also correct
butt ill get error device id null
how to rectify this ?
